# Qt with OpenCV: LNK2019:unresolved external symbol and File not Found mainwindow.obj

Tags: qt, opencv

I am trying to build an example qt-opencv project `Hello_Qt_OpenCV`that is provided by [Computer-Vision-with-OpenCV-3-and-Qt5](https://github.com/PacktPublishing/Computer-Vision-with-OpenCV-3-and-Qt5/tree/master/ch02/Hello_Qt_OpenCV). I use QtCreator4.5 with Qt5.7 and opencv3.2. Their configurations work fine with some other qt-opencv projects.

Building the project gives three issues:

`File not found: mainwindow.obj: LNK2019: unresolved external symbol` "void __cdecl cv::medianBlur(class cv::_InputArray const &,class cv::_OutputArray const &,int)" (?medianBlur@cv@@YAXAEBV_InputArray@1@AEBV_OutputArray@1@H@Z) referenced in function "private: void __cdecl MainWindow::on_outputPushButton_pressed(void)" (?on_outputPushButton_pressed@MainWindow@@AEAAXXZ)

`File not found: mainwindow.obj: LNK2019: unresolved external symbol` "void __cdecl cv::GaussianBlur(class cv::_InputArray const &,class cv::*OutputArray const &,class cv::Size*,double,double,int)" (?GaussianBlur@cv@@YAXAEBV_InputArray@1@AEBV_OutputArray@1@V?$Size_@H@1@NNH@Z) referenced in function "private: void __cdecl MainWindow::on_outputPushButton_pressed(void)" (?on_outputPushButton_pressed@MainWindow@@AEAAXXZ)

```
LNK1120: 2 unresolved externals release\Hello_Qt_OpenCV.exe:-1: error
```

I tried some suggestions at ([File not found: mainwindow.obj](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15864177/file-not-found-mainwindow-obj) by `clean`, `run qmake` and `build`, which however won't work in this case.

For your information, I post the mainwindow.cpp and mainwindow.h:

mainwindow.cpp:

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    loadSettings();
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}

void MainWindow::on_inputPushButton_pressed()
{
    QString fileName = QFileDialog::getOpenFileName(this, "Open Input Image", QDir::currentPath(), "Images (*.jpg *.png *.bmp)");
    if(QFile::exists(fileName))
    {
        ui->inputLineEdit->setText(fileName);
    }
}

void MainWindow::on_outputPushButton_pressed()
{
    QString fileName = QFileDialog::getSaveFileName(this, "Select Output Image", QDir::currentPath(), "*.jpg;;*.png;;*.bmp");
    if(!fileName.isEmpty())
    {
        ui->outputLineEdit->setText(fileName);
        using namespace cv;
        Mat inpImg, outImg;
        inpImg = imread(ui->inputLineEdit->text().toStdString());
        if(ui->medianBlurRadioButton->isChecked())
            cv::medianBlur(inpImg, outImg, 5);
        else if(ui->gaussianBlurRadioButton->isChecked())
            cv::GaussianBlur(inpImg, outImg, Size(5, 5), 1.25);
        imwrite(fileName.toStdString(), outImg);
        if(ui->displayImageCheckBox->isChecked())
            imshow("Output Image", outImg);
    }
}

void MainWindow::closeEvent(QCloseEvent *event)
{
    int result = QMessageBox::warning(this, "Exit", "Are you sure you want to close this program?", QMessageBox::Yes, QMessageBox::No);
    if(result == QMessageBox::Yes)
    {
        saveSettings();
        event->accept();
    }
    else
    {
        event->ignore();
    }
}

void MainWindow::loadSettings()
{
    QSettings settings("Packt", "Hello_OpenCV_Qt", this);
    ui->inputLineEdit->setText(settings.value("inputLineEdit", "").toString());
    ui->outputLineEdit->setText(settings.value("outputLineEdit", "").toString());
    ui->medianBlurRadioButton->setChecked(settings.value("medianBlurRadioButton", true).toBool());
    ui->gaussianBlurRadioButton->setChecked(settings.value("gaussianBlurRadioButton", false).toBool());
    ui->displayImageCheckBox->setChecked(settings.value("displayImageCheckBox", false).toBool());
}

void MainWindow::saveSettings()
{
    QSettings settings("Packt", "Hello_OpenCV_Qt", this);
    settings.setValue("inputLineEdit", ui->inputLineEdit->text());
    settings.setValue("outputLineEdit", ui->outputLineEdit->text());
    settings.setValue("medianBlurRadioButton", ui->medianBlurRadioButton->isChecked());
    settings.setValue("gaussianBlurRadioButton", ui->gaussianBlurRadioButton->isChecked());
    settings.setValue("displayImageCheckBox", ui->displayImageCheckBox->isChecked());
}
```

mainwindow.h:

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QFileDialog>
#include <QDir>
#include <QFile>
#include <QCloseEvent>
#include <QMessageBox>
#include <QSettings>
#include "opencv2/opencv.hpp"

namespace Ui {
class MainWindow;
}

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~MainWindow();

protected:
    void closeEvent(QCloseEvent *event);

private slots:
    void on_inputPushButton_pressed();

    void on_outputPushButton_pressed();

private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;

    void loadSettings();
    void saveSettings();

};

#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

You may also download the project files and give a quick run to see if the issues are related to the project itself.

Answer (score 0):

Add `imgproc320` in the `.pro` file, and then the problem is solved

Comment: Where did you get the files of Open CV for QT?